# Erlang data structures

Tags: data-structures, erlang

I'm a bit confused about what data structure I can use to be able to do following tasks rather fast:

1. Save tuples (can be changed to contain a keyword). Will be something like {UserInfo, Time, TimeLvl}
2. Remove element knowing the tuple (or the keyword)
3. Update all contained elements, changing one of the tuple's elements about once a second (TimeLvl will get higher the longer the user waits).

The Contained data will change a lot as users come and go.

What would be the best data-structure for this use case?

Comment: You need `records` together with `ETS Tables`, check here: http://20bits.com/articles/erlang-an-introduction-to-records/,here http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/records.html, and here http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/records.html. Be warned not to use any other data structure for what you have described above: erlang records are what you need. read about them, learn them. They are the building structures for most of the advanced data structures in Erlang

Comment: Internally, records are represented using tagged tuples. And since it really is a small piece of code. I think tuples are better.

Comment: Believe me, tuples will make you use functions such as `set_element/3`, `element/2`. These are not efficient as seen from the efficiency guide. records are never too much or too small for the task. They make the code clean and manageable. You must not even think of tuples, because it was for that reason that records were added to the language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this article: [Key-Value stores](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/a-short-visit-to-common-data-structures#key-value-stores).

Than decide which of the data structures presented is best suited for you. 
The article also provides a benchmark.

I personally like [gb_trees](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gb_trees.html), which is quite fast and easy to use.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [gproc](https://github.com/uwiger/gproc)

It should do what you want, it is very efficient, and made by one of the creator of Erlang, so robust enough.

You can check some gproc capabilities [here](http://rustyklophaus.com/articles/20090916-GProcErlangGlobalProcessRegistry.html), then you will know if it fits your problem

EDIT 1 : 
After further search, updating the Value of a gproc entry can be done with `gproc:set_value(Key, Value).`

EDIT 2 :
So you will use :

```
gproc:reg({n, l, YouKey}, YourValue)   %% YouValue will be the tuple
gproc:set_value(YourKey, YourValue)
gproc:unreg({n, l, YourKey})
```

Comment: But gproc is used as process dictionary while I want to save tuples. Also, how could I update all contained Elements?

Comment: gproc isn't only used as process dictionary

Comment: `gproc` (according to me) is a wrong choice. Records and ETS tables fit very well the solution. `gproc` is glued to the process that saved the terms. `gproc` is meant for concurrent data where by a process will need its data fast as it executes several functions. `gproc` is not meant for this problem.

Comment: since it seemed to be a multiple Clients server, and I assumed that each client were a pid, I thought that the fact gproc is process oriented would have been a plus... Apparently I was wrong